# read in matrix into r without delimination

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

a file I want to read into R looks liek this

```
0010101010101010101
1110101010101010101
1111110101010111000
0001010101000010100
```

when I read that in the problem is that R thinks every row is a number and just shows

```
   V1
1 Inf
2 Inf
3 Inf
4 Inf
5 Inf
6 Inf
```

how can I read it in as a matrix with 0 and the other element?

Answer (score 3):

One option is

```
as.matrix(read.fwf('triub.txt', widths=rep(1,19)))
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19
#[1,]  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
#[2,]  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
#[3,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
#[4,]  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

Or

```
as.matrix(read.table(text=gsub("", ' ', readLines('triub.txt'))))
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19
#[1,]  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
#[2,]  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
#[3,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
#[4,]  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

Or you can `pipe` with `sed` or `awk` (in `linux`)

```
 as.matrix(read.table(pipe("sed 's/./& /g' triub.txt"), header=FALSE))
 #    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19
 #[1,]  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
 #[2,]  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
 #[3,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
 #[4,]  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0

as.matrix(read.table(pipe("awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"\"; OFS=\" \"}{$1=$1}1' triub.txt"),
     header=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could treat it like a fixed with data file and use the new `readr` library.

```
library(readr)
read_fwf("0010101010101010101
1110101010101010101
1111110101010111000
0001010101000010100", fwf_widths(rep(1,19)))
```

this returns a data.frame which you can convert to matrix with `as.matrix`

Or you could read the lines and split (useful if you don't know the number of columns ahead of time)

```
tx<-textConnection("0010101010101010101
1110101010101010101
1111110101010111000
0001010101000010100")


do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(readLines(tx), strsplit, split=""), as.numeric))

close(tx)
```

Note I only use `textConnection()` here to make a reproducible example. You can use `readLines("filename.txt")` for your real data file.