# Read a file without delimination to R as a matrix

Tags: r

I have a very big file like this (no separator between characters):

```
1234
3456
2345
```

I want to read it to R as a matrix and get this:

```
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6 
2 3 4 5
```

This question is like this question: [read in matrix into r without delimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569126/read-in-matrix-into-r-without-delimination) but I am looking for a better way. I do not want to put the number of columns - I want the number of columns to be a variable in the code and support big files.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
library(readr)

my_file <- "big_file.txt"

my_matrix <- as.matrix(read_fwf(my_file, fwf_widths(rep(1,nchar(readLines(my_file, n=1))))))
```

nchar(readLines(my_file, n=1)) reads the first line and counts the number of characters. This is the multiplier of for the rep() for specifying the fwf_widths.

This assumption being that all your numbers are integers between 0 and 9.

Comment: It is read.fwf NOT read_fwf.

Comment: @ShenglinChen, it is read_fwf in the readr package. Please read correctly.